# Media Query detection on windows mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, nokia

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 320px)").matches) {
    alert("width 320"); // works
}
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    alert("width 768");
}
if (window.matchMedia("(min-resolution: 2.4dppx)").matches) {
    alert("2.4dppx");
} 
if (window.matchMedia("(min-resolution: 217dpi)").matches) {
    dpi = 217;
} 
if (window.matchMedia("(min-resolution: 252dpi)").matches) {
    dpi = 252;
} 
if (window.matchMedia("(min-resolution: 331dpi)").matches) {
    dpi = 331;
} 
if (window.matchMedia("(min-resolution: 332dpi)").matches) {
    dpi = 332;
    }
```

I'm testing on Lumia 920 and only `width 320` works, none other, I want to know the DPI. Tried everything, its just min-resolution that doesn't work.

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/phone/lumia920/specifications/) all your queries should match.

Comment: Exactly, but they aren't. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you have only min-width defined.
if you are searching for min-width:320px - this query is met always - even you have bigger resolution.
Try something like

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767)").matches) {
    alert("width 320"); // works
}//one px less then the query in next statement
```